Do MCMC chain lengths affect model comparison?
Say I have two Bayesian regression models fit to the the same data. For whatever reason, the second model takes longer to converge, so I run the MCMC sampling chain twice as long for the second model as for the first one. Are these models still comparable with WAIC or LOO-CV, even though they have different numbers of posterior samples?
